# Does Dean's reaper, Tessa always appear the same?

Tags: supernatural

Ever since being possessed by Azazel, Tessa has appeared to Dean as Tessa, a young woman with brown hair.

This is despite reapers not having an age, gender etc.

Is this Tessa making an effort for Dean, or does she sppear the same to everyone else and has never changed back?

Answer (score 2):

She initially took that appearance intentionally, to try to convince Dean to do the death thing. I assume that she now appears to him that way out of habit, probably doesn't take much effort. If not that, then it certainly facilitates communication... she couldn't talk to him in her more natural appearance.

We've seen others, one of which took human form without prompting, and another that looked like a zombie with a hangover (but we saw it from the audience's perspective, and not from that of the soon-to-be deceased, so it might be a selective effect).

And though some might be irritated that I'll say it... it certainly saves on the per-episode special effects budget for her to be played by an actress.

Comment: `zombie with a hangover`...  Are you talking [about this one](http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb57526/supernatural/images/7/7b/In_My_Time_of_Dying_Reaper.jpg)?  'Cause that _is_ Tessa, in her true form.

Comment: No. An earlier episode, Dean has heart damage. A reaper is bound magically to prevent people from dying, etc.

Comment: Ahh, [this guy](http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb57525/supernatural/images/c/cb/Reaps.jpg)?

Comment: Yeh, him. That was season one I think, but it's difficult to remember.

Comment: I can't remember -- can Sam see Tessa in the episode where Alistair is trying to kill a reaper to break a seal? Did she look like Tessa to him too?

Comment: Definitely. Both he and Dean have a conversation with her.

Comment: This doesn't address whether or not she keeps that form when not hanging out with the Winchesters.

Comment: It's very doubtful that she'd bother, unless communicating with the recently-deceased. Though, I suspect she does for non-Winchesters at this point.

Comment: This last comment is the answer I'm after. That the fundamentally changed due to Dean